# Remove stop times from ResourcePool for OEE calculations

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to calculate the OEE of a manufacturing process. However, when the ResourcePool "workers" are in their break or when they don't work (weekends), the products rely on the line, so this time is being counted as manufacturing time.

For this reason, I want to define the variable "noworkingTime", to substract this time from the total manufacturing time. I have tried to use this structure in some parts of the process:

```
if(workers.sizeActive()==0){
noworkingTimeStart=time();}

if(workers.sizeActive()!=0){
noworkingTime+=time()-noworkingTimeStart;}
```

But nothing really works... Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.
 `sizeActive()` Is the correct function to use as it returns the total number of resource units in the current shift. But depending on where you use it, and how might be the problem. Please provide more information about your model and where and how you use the function.

Comment: I think now is working. In the ReosurcePool "workers" I wrote in 'On seize':
    if(noworkingTimeStart>0){
    noworkingTime+=time()-noworkingTimeStart;
    noworkingTimeStart=0;}

And in 'On release':
    if(workers.sizeActive()==0){
    noworkingTimeStart=time();}